# how to fix this casting error for Relativelayout

Tags: java, android, android-layout

[need help for this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CT1n2.png)

[This is the line where i'm getting the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KsjAK.png)

Comment: Posting images of code and errors is frowned upon here, because it makes it more difficult for us to help you with your issue.  It is always better to copy and paste the relevant code and/or errors into your question directly.  Please read [Why not to upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-to-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question), then [edit] your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your id of `relativelayout` in xml file. It seems id `rootlayout` belongs to `constraint layout`. Change id for relative layout same in xml file.

Or Change your `rootlayout` decleration to

```
ContraintLayout rootlayout = (ConstraintLayout) findViewById(R.id.rootlayout);
```

Comment: Welcome. glad to help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't cast the object because it is a different type, for example take this code:

```
public class Fruit {
    protected int size;

    public Fruit(int size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}

public class Banana extends Fruit {

    private Color color;

    public Banana(int size, Color color) {
        super(size);
        this.color = color;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Fruit someFruit = new Fruit(5);
        Banana yellowNanner = new Banana(3, Color.YELLOW);
        Fruit greenBanana = new Banana(4, Color.GREEN);            

        // Allowed cast because Banana is a fruit (extends it, no need to explicitly cast) [1]
        Fruit generalBanana = yellowNanner;

        // Allowed cast because The fruit was a banana originally [2]
        Banana stillABanana = (Banana) greenBanana;

        // Disallowed cast because Fruit isn't necessarily a banana [3]
        Banana notABanana = (Banana) someFruit; // gives a runtime exception (ClassCastException)

        // Disallowed cast, String isn't related to fruit [4]
        Fruit definitelynotfruit = (Fruit) "Pretend to be fruit"; // gives a runtime exception, and probably a compiler one too
    }
}
```

The point I am trying to make is that you are casting something that can't be cast. Check if the thing you are trying to cast to actually is a superclass or the same level as the class it's coming from.

The case you are experiencing is probably [3] or [4]

But judging from: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html
and: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html

RelativeLayout is a subclass from View.
android.support.constraint.Constraintlayout is a subclass from View

```
but a android.support.constraint.Constraintlayout can't be cast to a RelativeLayout
```

What you basically are trying to do is

```
RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout) constraintLayout;
```

where RelativeLayout is not a superclass of constraintLayout.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sir. your explanation helps a lot to me, i really appreciate your effort.

Comment: You are welcome, if there is anything you still don't understand comment below.